# Do OrmLite & greenDAO execute query in background thread and do they load result partially into memory?

Tags: android, orm, ormlite, greendao

In order to avoid blocking the main/UI thread, Android API provides [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) for accessing database. In order to save memory (RAM), the API does not load the whole rows (result) into memory, so that we can have a `ListView` containing so many items without out-of-memory.

Do [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) & [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) provides both of these capabilities? If not, is there any approach to do asynchronous query and partial load-and-swap for populating *huge* data into a `ListView`?

Comment: Any notice on this question? I have the same question and I really think that using the Android default components is better than using GreenDAO.

Comment: I am still waiting for the answer. So far, I don't see that both of them execute query asynchronously and load result rows partially.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ORM-frameworks provide the ability to only load row-parts.

With greendao you can use `listLazy()` on your `Query` to load the entities lazily from DB. This introduces great performance benefit over "prefetching" all entities.

I know that greendao also provides some way to asynchronously load entities with an `AsyncSession`. But I currently don't know how this is to be used.

Normally all the CRUD-operations in greendao happen on the same thread that invoked update and such.

I haven't used OrmLite yet, so I have no information about this.

Comment: @DamodarPeriwal No Problem. As I said: IMHO your comment fits to this thread, but not on this answer...

Answer (score 0):

I can't pronounce over OrmLite but with greenDAO I know that you can execute raw queries on the db. After all under all that generated code lies an SQLITE database.

Take a look over NoteActivity in the greenDAO example project:
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoExample/src/main/java/de/greenrobot/daoexample/NoteActivity.java

In onCreate() you can clearly see that the cursor is fetched like this:

> DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "db_name", null);
>   SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
>   DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
>   DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
>   ObjectDao objectDao = daoSession.getObjectDao();
>   [..]
>   Cursor cursor = db.query(objectDao.getTablename(), objectDao.getAllColumns(), null, null, null, null, null);

As you can see this cursor can be used as any other cursor to display the data.
Now, doing this on the main thread is wrong and this is done just to expose a functionality. What you can do from this (since you mentioned loaders):

1. Keep a single instance of db / daoSession per app. Ideally move the code into the application class or create a singleton to handle it
2. Create a loader and override loadInBackground(). In that method run the db query and return the cursor. Use the loader result with a cursor adapter and display your data.